# Microsoft Edge PDF Viewer Extension Location

Tags: javascript, pdf, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I am interested in messing with the built-in PDF viewer of Microsoft Edge. I know you can inspect its files in the Dev console, but I would like to know where these files are actually located so I can change them to alter/add some functionality.
Another possibility would be to run a user script when a PDF is loaded, but tampermonkey does not seem to work when a PDF file is opened in Edge.

Why I want to do this: I would like to see whether I can implement additional functions that I'd like to use in the PDF viewer. I know there are pdf js libraries out there, but I feel like none of them display pdfs as nicely as Edge does and I haven't found one that allows drawing on pdfs.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's true, but if you inspect the pdf viewer, it says extension://blablabla...

Comment: LOL! Yeah, it was a stupid comment really, because I've definitely seen "built-in extensions" before. :-)

Comment: @KJ That's not what I meant. I know where the pdf files are located, but I care about the location of the javascript files displaying the pdf inline in the browser.

Comment: @KJ How come that one can inspect any pdf opened in edge and always find the same js files interacting with the pdf, i.e. when saving it? There are a lot of js files under {{edge pdf viewer built-in extension}}/edge_pdf, that handle zoom, rotation, drawing, saving etc., at least in my version of edge (92.0.902.45)

Comment: @KJ They are not edgium replacement pdf extensions. They are the default edge pdf viewer files. I don't use edge extensions either.

Comment: The PDF reader gets deployed and updated with the rest of the Microsoft Edge browser. This means the PDF reader related functions should be related to the source code design. If you need to modify or add to its functions, I think this should not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the edge_pdf source code by inspect the page ,then click the Source panel, it show all the resource which edge_pdf loaded.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's what I've been saying, but where are these files located? In which folder are they saved? Is there are way to find out from the dev console?